# Brief history of primality testing theory after 2002?

Tags: prime-numbers, ho.history-overview, computational-number-theory

Its clear that there is about 15 years (2004-2019) after the publication of AKS primality testing in 2002 and its modifications in 2003-2004. AS result, is there any development happened in this theory after 2004 ?

Comment: For developments until now one would say a survey rather than history. History requires hindsight.